# Enciphering SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, sqlcipher

I have an app on android that uses a Sqlite database. I want to make it impossible to access to the database without password. What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: if the user has root, than this is not possible. Take a look at this, maybe it is an option: https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/

Comment: assuming the user has NO root, of course.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to protect database file, add encryption to it with some password. There are some open source libraries are available. Most popular is [***`SQLCipher`***](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/).

If you use [***`SQLCipher`***](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/), even if somebody pulls out your application's .db file, he wont be able to read it (He can read file but in encrypted format). Only entities from application can read/write to it.